# Edit db context to get name from related entity

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I am new to VS2019, EF and .net Core 3.1, so please bear with me with me.

dbcontext

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Books>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Createdon)
                .HasColumnName("createdon")
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

            entity.Property(e => e.Goal)
                .HasColumnName("goal")
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Grade)
                .HasColumnName("grade")
                .HasMaxLength(2)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Subjectid).HasColumnName("subjectid");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Subject)
                .WithMany(p => p.Books)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.Subjectid)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Books_Subjects");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Subjects>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Createdby).HasColumnName("createdby");

            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .HasColumnName("name")
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        });
```

Here I want to get the **Subject name** from Subject entity when I retrieve Books.
Unfortunatly I do not have EF Desginer Model available (dont know why).
Is it possible to do this through dbcontext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is a one-to-many relation between Books and Subjects: every Book has exactly one Subject, namely the one that the foreign key SubjectId refers to. Every Subject is the subject of zero or more Books.

Now you want (some properties of) Books, each book with its Subject Name, and maybe some other Subject properties.

If your Book class has property `virtual Subject Subject {get; set;}`, you can use that property to get it. Entity framework knows the one-to-many relation and knows how to convert it into the proper (Group-)Join.

If the classes don't have this property, you should do the Join yourself:

### Use the virtual property

```
class Subject
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // Every Subject is the subject of zero or more Books (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books {get; set;}
}
class Book
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // Every Book has exactly one Subject, using foreign key:
    public int SubjectId {get; set;}
    public virtual Subject Subject {get; set;}
}
```

This is all that entity framework needs to know to detect your one-to-many relationship.

```
var booksWithTheirSubjectNames = dbContext.Books

    // only if you don't want all Books
    .Where(book => ...)

    .Select(book => new
    {
        // Select the Book properties that you plan to use:
        Id = book.Id,
        Title = book.Title,
        ...

        // Select the subject properties that you plan to use
        Subject = new
        {
             Name = book.Subject.Name,
             Description = book.Subject.Description,
             ...
        },
    });
```

### Do the Join yourself

If you have a one-to-many relation, you have a one-side and a many-side. To get the "item with its zero or more subItems" use a `GroupJoin`, to get the "item with the only parent item that the foreign key refers to" use `Join`.

```
var booksWithTheirSubjectNames = dbContext.Books.Join(dbContext.Subjects,

    book => book.SubjectId,     // from every Book take the foreign key
    subject => subject.Id,      // from every Subject take the primary key

    // when they match, take the Book and the Subject to make one new object:
    (book, subject) => new
    {
        Id = book.Id,
        Title = book.Title,
        ...

        Subject = new
        {
             Name = book.Subject.Name,
             Description = book.Subject.Description,
             ...
        },
    });
```